# can't do POST to api, error 400 using fetch

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, fetch

```
fetch('/auth/signup', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: this.state.user,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    })
```

this.state.user is basically an object like `{user: {name:"someone"}` and my server side code simply do this

```
router.post('/signup', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body) // empty object
}
```

I think something is wrong with `fetch`, didn't see any data been pass in the network tab.

Comment: Do you see a certain message in your [console] window?

Comment: @eeya 400 error, bad request

Comment: On your [fetch] method, what happens when you replace the url to 'signup' instead of 'auth/signup'?

Comment: @eeya now I manage to pass data but server return req.body as {} hmmm...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass `this.state.user` to `JSON.stringify()` before setting at `body` or use `FormData` to `POST` key, value pairs. `body` does not expect `javascript` object.

```
body: JSON.stringify(this.state.user)
```

```
let fd = new FormData();
let {user} = this.state.user;
for (let prop in user) {
  fd.append(prop, JSON.stringify(user[prop]));
}
```

```
body: fd
```